# 2008 equinox doesn't have heat on idle and very little driving

Tags: cooling-system, cooling

getting very little heat while driving and idle if i turn up fan inside car goes cold, temp gauge goes to half and stops, also getting a noise like a loose belt but once the car is warm noise stops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a number of things:

1. Not enough coolant, check level. If it´s missing some see if it holds level now or if it losses coolant.
2. If something was done that required a drain of the cooling system, it may not have been bled correctly after refill and have some air-bubbles in it.
3. Thermostat may be broken, replace, refill, bleed system.
4. Water pump may need replacement. Did you stick to the recommendet change interval?

Comment: coolant level is good and i recently had my radiator fan replaced , so im thinking system needs to be bled ,  thanks